# Google Cloud DNS not resolving hosted domain

Tags: google-cloud-dns

I am using google cloud DNS for a domain. But for some reason, it is not resolving

```
root@ok:~# nslookup insurancegurukul.com
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 1.1.1.1, trying next server
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find insurancegurukul.com: SERVFAIL

root@ok:~#
```

Name servers used for the domain is

```
root@ok:~# whois  insurancegurukul.com -h whois.internic.net | grep -i "Name Server:"
   Name Server: NS-CLOUD-A1.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
   Name Server: NS-CLOUD-A2.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
   Name Server: NS-CLOUD-A3.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
   Name Server: NS-CLOUD-A4.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
root@ok:~#
```

The domain resolve properly if i check with one of these name servers.

Any idea why the domain is not resolving ?

```
root@ok:~# nslookup insurancegurukul.com NS-CLOUD-A2.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
Server:     NS-CLOUD-A2.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
Address:    216.239.34.106#53

Name:   insurancegurukul.com
Address: 148.66.135.207

root@ok:~#
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Comment: Well, that's interesting @JohnHanley. You should post on [meta] suggesting a change to the scope of SO. Go on. Do it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by DNSSEC.

Whois of the domain had "DNSSEC: signedDelegation".

```
boby@ok-pc-01:~$ whois insurancegurukul.com
   Domain Name: INSURANCEGURUKUL.COM
   Registry Domain ID: 1715752075_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
   Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.godaddy.com
   Registrar URL: http://www.godaddy.com
   Updated Date: 2018-11-15T16:35:06Z
   Creation Date: 2012-04-24T19:39:21Z
   Registry Expiry Date: 2025-04-24T19:39:21Z
   Registrar: GoDaddy.com, LLC
   Registrar IANA ID: 146
   Registrar Abuse Contact Email: abuse@godaddy.com
   Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: 480-624-2505
   Domain Status: clientDeleteProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientDeleteProhibited
   Domain Status: clientRenewProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientRenewProhibited
   Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
   Domain Status: clientUpdateProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientUpdateProhibited
   Name Server: NS-CLOUD-A1.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
   Name Server: NS-CLOUD-A2.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
   Name Server: NS-CLOUD-A3.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
   Name Server: NS-CLOUD-A4.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
   DNSSEC: signedDelegation
   DNSSEC DS Data: 49912 8 1 45F45DDBA94938BF66B2D6E8759F923428F1FDCF
   DNSSEC DS Data: 18010 8 1 C0B1CC85941CFA008FD6905EE13813B65F917F63
```

This is disabled in domain registar godaddy > domain > DNS > DNSSEC

Once this is done, DNS resolution started working properly.